# Online account not responding

Tags: gnome, 22.10, online-accounts, google-drive

I want to add my Google Drive to sync a specific folder on my home PC to access it from anywhere. I processed to do that by adding my Google account to the gnome online accounts, but sadly it's not working. Would you please help me find a solution.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 gnome 43

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1446490/edit) your question to include more details?  *"Not working"* is quite vague ;-).  Thanks!